# How one can find a criterion that gives a clear distinction between the two mentioned classes of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, infinity

Consider the set of all real sequences (different from the zero sequence) that have the value zero on their elements. We can classify this set in two subsets: (1) one with finite number of zeros and (2) one with infinite number of zeros.

My **question** is: How one can find a property or a criterion that gives a clear distinction between the two mentioned classes of sequences.

Comment: Whether there is a $0$ subsequence?

Comment: @DonThousand: How this is possible.

Comment: Like, if there is a $0$ subsequence, then there are infinite $0$s. If there are infinite $0$s, the subsequence of those infinite $0$s is a $0$ subsequence.

Comment: @DonThousand: and again the same question how one can find a zero subsequence.

Comment: What do you mean by "find"

Comment: @DonThousand: Find a condition.

Comment: I gave you a condition.

Comment: @DonThousand: But it is the same as asking about the original sequence.

Comment: That's how conditions work. You wanted a condition which is equivalent to the original sequence. That's what I gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set ${\cal S}$ of all real-valued sequences ${\bf x}=(x_n)_{n\geq0}$ is divided into two parts ${\cal A}$ and ${\cal B}$. A sequence ${\bf x}\in {\cal S}$ is in ${\cal A}$ if there is an $N\in{\mathbb N}$ such that $x_n\ne0$ for all $n>N$, and is in ${\cal B}$ otherwise.

Note that this "criterion" just repeats more or less verbatim the definition of the distinction ${\cal A}$ vs. ${\cal B}$ you gave in your question. There is not more to say.